# L'article partitif après « besoin »

Tags: articles, partitif

On dit

> j'ai besoin de fruits

mais

> je mange des fruits.

Je pense qu'on pourrait dire

> j'ai besoin des fruits

si et seulement si il y a des fruits particuliers dont on a besoin, mais avec "mange" la même distinction est fait avec "les fruits" (pas de "de").

C'est quoi la différence entre "avoir besoin" et "manger" ? C'est sémantique ou syntaxique ?

Comment: Syntaxique. *Je mange quelque chose* (pas de préposition) et *J'ai besoin de quelque chose* (*de* est une préposition dans ce cas.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il n'y a pas d'article partitif ici, mais l'article indéfini pluriel et la différence de sens est celle normale entre l'article défini (les) et l'article indéfini (des).  Elle est un peu obscurcie parce qu'il y a une contraction avec la préposition *de*.

*On mange quelque chose* (pas de préposition) et *on a besoin **de** quelque chose* (*de* est une préposition).  Or

*De* préposition suivi de *des* article indéfini se contracte en *de*.

*De* préposition suivi de *les* article défini se contracte en *des*.

Donc

*Je mange les fruits* est à mettre en parallèle avec *j'ai besoin <s>de les</s> des fruits*.

*Je mange des fruits* est à mettre en parallèle avec *j'ai besoin <s>de des</s> de fruits*.

Answer (score 1):

Il n'y a pas de différence d'utilisation lorsqu'il s'agit de nourriture, seulement l'intention de dire si l'on parle du moment de l'action ou de son principe :

> J'*ai besoin* de fruits et *je mange* du pain pour avoir une nourriture
>   équilibrée.
>  Je *mange* un fruit et *j'ai besoin* de pain pour avoir une nourriture
>   équilibrée.
>
> J'*aurai besoin* des fruits fournis par les maraîchers locaux et *je mangerai* des pains régionaux lors de la prochaine exposition culinaire de la ville.
>   Je *mangerai* des fruits fournis par les maraîchers locaux et *j'aurai besoin* de pains régionaux lors de la prochaine exposition culinaire de la ville.

... il n'est pas certain que les substantifs d'*avoir besoin* soient destinés à ma consommation personnelle dans ce dernier cas.

*Avoir besoin* et *manger* ne couvrent pas la même réalité :
J'*ai besoin* de planter un clou pour accrocher un tableau, mais les clous ne se *mangent* pas.